# Linux post message to server

Tags: linux, post, lwp

I have some hard time to post some data to the webserver on specified link. I have a task in what I have to post a code - 125 - with my username specified as my nickname to localhost/zad.php

I tried various things. POST comes from lwp-request and I am trying to use it with no success.

> lwp-request post -c 125 -C mzajac localhost/zad.php

EDIT:

Now I done something quite right I think.

```
lwp-request -m POST -C mzajac localhost
Please enter content (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) to be POSTed:
125
^C
```

I enter 125 but nothing happens like it is waiting for more. So how can I be sure that 125 was sent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't mind to use `wget`

```
wget --post-data "code=125&username=mzajac " localhost/zad.php
```

Change `code` and `username` according to what's expected by `zad.php`

Answer (score 4):

Use ^D (UNIX) or ^Z (DOS) to end your arguments.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/End-of-transmission_character

Example:

```
lwp-request -m POST -C mzajac:password http://localhost/zad.php
Please enter content (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) to be POSTed:
code=125
^D
```